# Summing up Pandas dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sum up multiple data frames in a loop so that I'll have one data frame that will show the total of all data frames.

Please see here the example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Header':['L1','L2','L3'], 'Val1':[float(100),float(200),float(300)],
         'Val2':[float(400),float(500),float(600)], 'Val3': 
         [float(700),float(800),float(900)]}
data1_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

# Inside loop it'll create two more such outputs but with different values but with the same labels.

data2 = {'Header':['L1','L2','L3'], 'Val1':[float(1000),float(1100),float(1200)],
         'Val2':[float(1300),float(1400),float(1500)], 'Val3': 
         [float(1600),float(1700),float(1800)]}
data2_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

data3 = {'Header':['L1','L2','L3'], 'Val1':[float(1900),float(2000),float(2100)],
         'Val2':[float(2200),float(2300),float(2400)], 'Val3': 
         [float(2500),float(2600),float(2700)]}
data3_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data3)
```

In the end, I am looking out for an out in 'data' data frame which will sum up all the values of data1 + data2 + data3. I tried pd.sum() but it adds up label text as well, I am only looking out for adding up values.

Comment: `out = (data1_summary.set_index('Header') + data2_summary.set_index('Header') + data3_summary.set_index('Header')).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by iterating through the list of **dataframes** and summing them up along the rows (axis=0).

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Define your dataframes
    data1 = {'Header': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'], 'Val1': [float(100), float(200), float(300)],
             'Val2': [float(400), float(500), float(600)], 'Val3': [float(700), float(800), float(900)]}
    data1_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
    data2 = {'Header': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'], 'Val1': [float(1000), float(1100), float(1200)],
             'Val2': [float(1300), float(1400), float(1500)], 'Val3': [float(1600), float(1700), float(1800)]}
    data2_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
    data3 = {'Header': ['L1', 'L2', 'L3'], 'Val1': [float(1900), float(2000), float(2100)],
             'Val2': [float(2200), float(2300), float(2400)], 'Val3': [float(2500), float(2600), float(2700)]}
    data3_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data3)
    # Create a list of dataframes
    dataframes = [data1_summary, data2_summary, data3_summary]
    # Sum up the dataframes
    total_data = pd.concat(dataframes).groupby('Header').sum().reset_index()
    print(total_data

)
```

Output:

```
  Header    Val1    Val2    Val3
0     L1  3000.0  3900.0  4800.0
1     L2  3300.0  4200.0  5100.0
2     L3  3600.0  4500.0  5400.0
```

Answer (score 3):

In loop create list of DataFrames:

```
dfs = []
#sample loop
for i in iter:
     #create DataFrames
     df = ...
     dfs.append(df)
```

Then join together and sum:

```
s = pd.concat(dfs).sum(numeric_only=True)
print (s)
Val1     9900.0
Val2    12600.0
Val3    15300.0
dtype: float64
```

Or sum per `Header`s:

```
out = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Header').sum()
print (out)
          Val1    Val2    Val3
Header                        
L1      3000.0  3900.0  4800.0
L2      3300.0  4200.0  5100.0
L3      3600.0  4500.0  5400.0
```